# Redirect terminal output to file

Tags: command-line, bash

I am looking for a `bash` command where I can redirect:

1. stdout of a command to a file
2. stderr to both that file and the console.

I have found ways where the stderr will append to the end of the file after the stdout, but I want it so that the output file orders all out the output chronologically like it would if I were to just use `command &> file`.

I have tried:

```
command 2>&1 1>logfile | tee -a logfile
command 2> >(tee -a logfile) 1>>logfile
```

I would basically like the output file to be same as if I simply did `command &> logfile`, whilst at the same time keep printing stderr messages to the console.

Comment: This stuff makes my head explode! I think you want a version of this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44285135/6929343 which uses `(cmd 2> >(tee /dev/stderr)) > log`. The question and all the answers have a combined up-votes of 1000+ so there must be heads exploding all over the world :D

Answer (score 2):

Let's create a test function that sends some output to both stdout and stderr:

```
$ cmd() { echo 1 on stdout; echo 2 on stderr >&2; echo 3 on stdout; echo 4 on stderr >&2; }
```

Running it we see:

```
$ cmd
1 on stdout
2 on stderr
3 on stdout
4 on stderr
```

Now, we want to send the stdout to a file, and the stderr to both the file and the screen. For this we use a simple redirection for stdout, and for stderr we redirect into a process substitution that appends to the file and sends the output back to stderr:

```
$ cmd > cmd.out 2> >( tee -a cmd.out >&2 )
2 on stderr
4 on stderr

$ cat cmd.out
1 on stdout
3 on stdout
2 on stderr
4 on stderr
```

I do not know of a way to keep the chronological order of the intermixed stdout and stderr messages.

Comment: Thanks, but yeah that's the result I'm getting right now. I wish there was some way to keep them in chronological order, since you are able to do that if you are redirecting all of output only to the file by using &>...

Comment: That regular, non-appending redirection (`> cmd.out`) is dangerous here. Depending on how the timing goes, the `stdout` output can overwrite the `stderr` output. Since `cmd.out` was opened twice, the file positions aren't locked together.

Comment: Great point. I was doing a test with some sleeps in between the echos, and the first stderr line got lost. This must be why. `>cmd.out; cmd >> cmd.out 2> >(tee -a cmd.out >&2)` would be the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

It works if you append stdout to the file and redirect stderr to `tee`, also appending to the file:

```
$ bash -c "echo a;bahs;echo b;bhas" >>file 2> >( tee -a file >&2 )
bash: bahs: command not found
bash: bhas: command not found
$ cat file
a
bash: bahs: command not found
b
bash: bhas: command not found
```

This *doesn’t* work with the test from glenn jackman’s answer and I can’t wrap my head around why.

Comment: That’s one of the worst answers I have ever written, but maybe someone can explain and teach me if this isn’t a solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can really do that.

When you redirect `stdout` and `stderr` separately, they become unsynchronized, and there's no way to fix them back again. What you're trying to do is something like this:

```
                  +------> terminal
                  |       
cmd -(stderr)--> tee ----> file
 |                          ^
 +---(stdout)---------------+
```

Here, there are two parallel paths from `cmd` to `file`, with an additional process in the `stderr` path. Depending on the scheduling, there might be delays in the path that involves `tee`, which can and will lead to the `stderr` messages being delayed.

To prevent that, the system would need to switch to `tee` immediately when it gets input. Usually, it can't be counted on to do that. Adding another process to the parallel path won't help, as then the result will just depend on the scheduling between the two intermediate processes (instead of `cmd` and `tee`).

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
echo "asd" | xargs -I % sh -c 'echo % && echo % > asd'
```

First echo is passed to xargs which takes it as argument and build two echo's commands, first result is output to terminal and second to file named also asd as the text.

You can put the redirects after in order to match your needs.